# View/Download Pdf Files in React - Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, create-react-app

I have a set of pdf files sitting in a folder in my project.

All I need to do is to create a link to these PDF files and view them in browser or download it.

I use React Router 4 and React 16 and create-react-app bootstrapping tool.

Regardless of how I link it (Link component  or a tag) it still goes to my last Route in my router config.

I have been googling for last two hours... But no luck..

Is there any way to tell router not to route for PDF/XLS files?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I met the same issue, I think it's because of the way CRA handles queries : I ended up putting my PDF files in the public folder, and link to them using :

```
{process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/myfile.pdf'}
```

as src to my  tags.

Not the best way I guess, but works fine enough...

Answer (score 30):

I tried squizz's way, but the problem I'm finding is that if you click the link more than once or twice, it will revert to going back to going to the last route.

You can make a folder in `src` to hold your pdf's, and link to them normally, ex:

```
import pdf from '../files/myfile.pdf'
render () {
    <a href={pdf}>Click here for my pdf</a>
}
```

The only problem is, you will get a hash appended to your file, so it will come out as myfile.d2e24234.pdf or something. I think it has to do with file-loader...currently trying to figure it out.

**EDIT**

The answer if you don't want to use src is to delete the service worker from the create-react-app project. For some reason it affects react-router's handling of server routes.

I made a github issue here to read about it: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/3608

Comment: you absolutely rescued me after 5 hours of hell! Thank you so much.

Comment: use this in your webpack config to get rid of the hash: use: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'

Comment: wow - you rescued me too!  I have been trying to solve this for hours -- Thank you for posting the answer I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this same issue and fixed it by resorting to old-fashioned html:

```
<a href="docs/document.pdf">
  Document
</a>
```

And copying the pdf to my publicly served folder with CopyWebpackPlugin in webpack.config:

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: 'docs/document.pdf',
        to: path.resolve(BUILD_PATH + "/docs/document.pdf")
      },
    ])
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<Link
    to="route"
    onClick={(event) => { event.preventDefault(); window.open(filePath); }}>
        Click to download
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come to find a lot of these answers were over complicating what I wanted to do so here's what worked for me. I dumped all of my pdf's into `/public/documents/<sample-consent-form.pdf>` and linked them this way. This will open up a view of the pdf in a new window without needed any custom components or libraries.

```
const consentLink = (
    <span>
        Please review our{" "}
        <a href="/documents/sample-consent-form.pdf" target="_blank">
            consent policy
        </a>{" "}
        before accepting
    </span>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in two different areas of my project, in the App component in the src folder and in a link from a child Navigation component. I created a 'docs' folder in the src directory and used require syntax to link to my file and it worked for me.

In the instance of the navigation component I accessed the file by changing the directory up two levels.

```
<Link href={require("../../docs/FILE_NAME.PDF")} target="blank">
      Resume
<Link>
```

In the instance of the App component I searched in the same directory.

```
<Link href={require("./docs/FILE_NAME.PDF")} target="blank">
      Resume
</Link>
```