# React - How to open PDF file as a href target blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

This mundane task fairly simple on static views, isn't complying with React.

Can someone advise me how to open a pdf file as a href on a new tab?

Here's my code using react-bootstrap and react-router:

```
    <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Forms">

        <MenuItem eventKey={3.1} href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Form 1</MenuItem>

        <MenuItem eventKey={3.2} href="samba.pdf" target="_blank">Form 2</MenuItem>
    </NavDropdown>
```

The external link to google works fine.

The pdf (saved on same level directory as the code above) doesnt.

When I click on the pdf link it redirects me to my "404 catch all" route.

```
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>;
```

**EDIT:**
Solution here:
[answered by Link_Cable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718289/view-download-pdf-files-in-react-router-4)

Comment: You don't have a route for `samba.pdf`, so it's falling through to your catch all. You'll either need to set your server up to serve that file first or add a route that handles it.

Comment: This is a client-side only app. So a dedicated route for "/file.pdf" should do the trick? Then, what component would I reference, since all I want is to load a pdf file 'externally'?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Place the pdf into a folder in /src. Import it like a component. Set `href` parameter as the imported pdf and the `target = "_blank"`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Pdf from '../Documents/Document.pdf';

class Download extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
        <div className = "App">
          <a href = {Pdf} target = "_blank">Download Pdf</a>
        </div>
    );

  }
}

export default Download;
```

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: is it open without download?

Comment: Yes, *pdf* will open on a new tab on Chrome/Explorer/Firefox/Safari.

Comment: its working but its not working after i did react-scripts build. How can i build it so that it can include pdf as well in production build.

Comment: It should work in production as well. What kind of error are you getting? Do you have the pdf inside your `/src` folder?

Comment: Just in case anyone stumble upon the same issue : I use React with Typescript, and could not import a `.pdf` file as a module. I could do it with more config : in `custom.d.ts`, I simply added :

```declare module '*.pdf' {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}```

At that point the solution worked.

Comment: Is document.pdf a actual pdf file to be displayed?

Answer (score 4):

I had to make a function to open the pdf in the new tab actually :D

```
import Pdf from "../../documents/resume.pdf";
onResumeClick() {
  window.open(Pdf);
}

render() { 
return (
   <a onClick={this.onResumeClick}>
      Resume
   </a>
)}
```

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use `require` function directly:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
    class Download extends Component {
    
      render() {
    
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <a href={require('../Documents/Document.pdf')} target="_blank">Download Pdf</a>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default Download;
```

Answer (score 2):

I placed the following in the header of the component I needed it in. The document was stored in Documents folder under src.

```
import Pdf from '../Documents/doc.pdf';
```

And then used the imported document in the tag using href.

```
<a href = {Pdf}>Resume</a>
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved that by creating `_someFolder` in the `public` folder and then in the component:

```
import {pdfFile} from "/_someFolder/pdfFile.pdf";

....

<div className="headerProfile-menu-list" onClick={() => window.open(pdfFile)}><i className="mdi mdi-help-circle"></i> Help</div>

....
```

that prevent by adding hashes to the filename when `serviceWorker` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Client side only? So there is no web server to host your web site? 
If you have a webserver then you could return the raw pdf content content back to the browser as "application/pdf" content type. Client side only would be to specify a relative path like

```
<a href="../FolderName/samba.pdf">
```

Comment: Adding the a tag above hasn't changed the behavior. It works fine on a plain index.html but not inside the React Bootstrap ecosystem. Plus the href needs to exist inside the <MenuItem/> Component.