# React Router - show PDF in new tab with window.open

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pdf

I am trying to display my PDF in the browser in a new tab but I have a feeling React Router is taking over and not displaying it correctly.

Here is my front end React function that is supposed to open the PDF:

```
const openPDF = (e) => {
    const prettyPDFName = e.target.textContent;
    openPDFAsync(prettyPDFName);

    console.log('pdfTextContent: ', prettyPDFName);
    const prettyFileName =
        prettyPDFName
            .substring(0, prettyPDFName.length - 4)
            .replace(/[ ,.]/g, '') + '.pdf';
    window.open(`/pdf/${prettyFileName}`, '_blank');
};
```

That opens a new tab with the correct URL in the address bar.  But it just shows my React app with the navigation at the top and blank content in the middle.

I found something on SO to prevent React Router from taking over for a specific route.  So in my app.js I tried this:

```
const pdf_regex = /^\/pdf\/.*/;
    // if using "/pdf/" in the pathname, don't use React Router

    if (pdf_regex.test(window.location.pathname)) {
        return <div />; // must return at least an empty div
    } else {
        // use React Router
        return (
            <Router>
            ...
```

That just displays a completely blank page and when I inspect, just an empty div which is to be expected I guess.

For more info, here is the Node code that gets called from the `openPDFAsync(prettyPDFName);` call:

```
router.get('/openPDFFile', async (req, res) => {
    const pretty_PDF_name = req.query.pdf;
    const pdfFilename = (await SDS.getPDFFileName({ pretty_PDF_name }))
        .dataValues.sheet_file_name;

    const cleanPDFName =
        pretty_PDF_name
            .substring(0, pretty_PDF_name.length - 4)
            .replace(/[ ,.]/g, '') + '.pdf';

    const pdfFilepath = `./path/to/file/${pdfFilename}`;
    console.log(cleanPDFName, pdfFilepath);
    router.get(cleanPDFName, async (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + pdfFilepath);
    });
```

Comment: Didn't this help > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572896/react-how-to-open-pdf-file-as-a-href-target-blank

Comment: No, that's not exactly what I'm doing.  They are importing the PDF from a local folder on the client it looks like.  I'm serving up the PDF from the server and just trying to hit that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just open a new window or set the href then,  so instead of returning just a div do one of the below

1. Parent window where your app exists - Has a message `<div> Return to homepage </div>` and do a `window.open(url)` which generates a new request, here have your node server handle the page directly without using the `App` middleware function that passes control to React router.
2. `window.location.href`- Remember, you are out of your app scope, I also believe passing target, whether `_self` or `_blank` will skip the router.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here.  I am opening a new window.  But React Router is handling the URL I think so it's not displaying the PDF.  And what do you mean by "Parent window"?

Comment: App.js is where I added this code: `if (pdf_regex.test(window.location.pathname)) {
  return <div />; // must return at least an empty div
 } else {
  // use React Router
  return (
   <Router>`  Is that what you mean by "Parent window"?

Comment: Yes, instead of the div - return a window.open