# Hyperlink to a pdf file using typescript in React Application

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This question seems asked many times here in this forum. But all of them clearly not helping my issue and that is why I thought to post it.

Problem statement:
While using href com in react application which navigates to a pdf file stored under public folder which is using typescript Giving a 404 not found error.

```
<a href = "/test.pdf" target = "_blank">HyperLink</a>
```

Folder structure

[image]

Can some one lead me here to identify the issue here? Or is there any other approach I can try out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - How to open PDF file as a href target blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572896/react-how-to-open-pdf-file-as-a-href-target-blank)

Comment: The issue am facing is related to path not able to import the file from thenfolder import Pdf from '../test.pdf'; it says   Cannot find module '/src/temp/test.pdf' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Comment: Where is this `<a href = "/test.pdf" target = "_blank">HyperLink</a>` placed ?

Comment: @SarunUK its placed under public folder and the place am trying to use this import is ContainerBody.tsx which is in src folder

Comment: Assuming the anchor is inside index.html. Then you have to access like this ----> `'./test.pdf'`

Comment: I've uploaded a PDF file to a [codesandbox](https://gzkno.csb.app/) in the root of the `public` directory and copy/pasted your link code into the react code and it appears to link fine, a new tab opens with the PDF. How/where is your code running?

Comment: @DrewReese the code is running in localhost

Comment: If you go to `http://localhost:3000/test.pdf` (*your port number may be different*) manually does the PDF file load?

Comment: @DrewReese https://localhost/test.pdf is giving me 404

Comment: If you are running a dev server locally there is most likely a port number you need to also specify. For react apps it is typically 3000, but this is 100% configurable, so as I said, you may be running your development server on a different port.

Answer (score -1):

You should import that image like this

```
import documentPdf from './public/test.pdf';
```

Then you can use it as a href source:

```
<a href={documentPdf} target="_blank">HyperLink</a>
```

Comment: Public folder isn't in the `src` directory, it needs an absolute path.

Comment: Tiago Vaccari : Thank you for the answer. I have tried that and am getting an error. 
Cannot find module './public/test.pdf' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307).

Comment: @harun the path './public/test.pdf' is just an example. For best practice, you should create a tmp or assets folder and copy that file in to it. Then, you should use the absolute path to get the file access.

Comment: @TiagoVaccari that I did . still the same error. no module found

Comment: This is because relative paths *only work* within the `src` directory.

Comment: @DrewReese have tried that as well . created a temp folder in the src folder and give the href as this <a href = "src/temp/test.pdf" target = "_blank">Harun Link</a> 
now throwing the error   : {"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"https://localhost/ege-partner-management-webapp/src/temp/test.pdf"}

in URL : https://localhost/ege-partner-management-webapp/src/temp/test.pdf

Comment: @harunprasu When your code is built, running, and served up, it won't have access to the source directory.

Comment: yes . It is deployed to the site itself right? localhost/ege-partner-management-webapp/src/temp/test.pdf some how it didn not found there