# Save pdf file in react js

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I have the following code in reactjs I would like to save pdf file that already exist in using the following code where to put the pdf file "Report" in doc. The pdf file are imported to the below code with name Report. How to make save for it using doc.save().

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Label, Form, Col, Row, Alert, Modal, Container, Card, CardImg, Dropdown, Table, InputGroup,FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap';


import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faFilter,faDownload,faUpload,faShare, faEye, faEyeSlash, faListCheck, faXmark, faPrint } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf'

import Report from '../../resources/Report.pdf';

class OnboardingGuide extends React.Component {
handleGetPDF  = () => {
   let doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt');
   doc.save('Report11.pdf') // saves pdf 
}

render() {
        return(   
<thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Onboarding Guide</th>
                  <th>PDF</th>  
                </tr>
              </thead> 
<tbody>
               
                  <tr>
              
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDownload} onClick={ this.handleGetPDF} style={{cursor: "pointer"}}/></td>
                    
                    
                  </tr>
       
              </tbody>
 )
        }

}

export default withRouter(OnboardingGuide);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, your tool `jspdf` enable you to generate a PDF but not the way you want. Since its not using a already existing pdf.

Try to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49882656/18244576) instead.

Comment: I want to download load it directly not open it. I want when click to be downloaded.

Comment: In any cases the method you are trying to use is not adapted to your use case.