# pdf document in react

Tags: reactjs, pdf, amazon-s3

I have a path to a pdf that is coming from a json file and i want to display this pdf in a react.js app

```
 <a href="./assets/pdf/pdf-name.pdf" type="application/pdf" className="" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" >Report</a>
```

I use this code and it works locally, but when i deploy it to aws (S3 + cloudfront) it doesn't work. I suspect the content type is not application/pdf and this is why the browser doesn't know what to do with it, so it loads an empty page within my application.

Is there a way to use a dynamic link to the pdf and have it displayed correctly?

I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718289/view-download-pdf-files-in-react-router-4) that i might have to import the pdf as a component, but that means i have to hardcore the pdfs in the source instead of taking them from the json. And even if I try to simply test it by hardcoding one link this way it still doesnt work.

Any clues on what I can do or where s the problem?